# ASP.net ListView Control Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, listview

I have designed a mockup design in Photoshop as follows http://i53.tinypic.com/1z5qdeq.jpg and I intend to "apply" it into my e-commerce site's ListView control. I've been reading through documentations on templates for ListView but don't know where I should get started. The part that I would like to implement is the design itself (the box and 2 buttons) into my ListView control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create templates. ListView allows you to have custom templates for layout and items that you can create programmatically but thats unnecessary for this. I'm assuming you have a repeating model of products that you show in the sample. Just use a regular list view as follows.

I would explain it all over again here but I think this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx) explains exactly what you need to. Let me know if thats not the case.

Comment: Hi coder net, when you mention repeating model, what do you mean by that?

Comment: list view basically repeats the same item layout for all items in your data source. Say you have 10 products in your list to display, and you specify your html for each item in the item template, it will repeat the same html layout (in your case, image, add to cart button etc) for all 10 of them.

Comment: Oh, right I believe i'm having a repeating model but how do i insert the add to cart button bit into the coding?

Comment: What you do is to create a product class with parameters such as ImageFileName, ProductName, etc etc.You bind the product list to the list view. In the article, where it shows the <itemtemplate> tags, you add all the properties you want displayed, such as image, product etc, and also add a <asp:button text="addtocart" onclick="event">. In the event, you get the  product id, (using a command argument perhaps), and add it to your shopping cart class. Look for shopping cart samples online.

Answer (score 3):

i hope this will do what you want simply;

- on aspx page

[image: sorry couldnt write code here]
 - on cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item() { ImageURL = "~/sample.jpg", Title = "samsung galaxy" });
        list.Add(new Item() { ImageURL = "~/sample.jpg", Title = "ipad" });
        list.Add(new Item() { ImageURL = "~/sample.jpg", Title = "xoom" });
        ListView1.DataSource = list;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```